# Resource handle of boost python

Tags: python, c++, boost

Using boost::python to call the python codes from c++.

```
int main()
{

namespace bp = boost::python;

Py_Initialize();
bp::object main_module = bp::import("__main__");
bp::import("ldap");
bp::import("ldif");
bp::object main_namespace = main_module.attr("__dict__");

bp::exec("import ldap,ldif\n"
         "l = ldap.initialize('ldaps://RIO-PC')\n",
         main_namespace);

//get the ldap object from the main_namespace
boost::python::object ldap = boost::python::extract<boost::python::object>(main_namespace["l"]);

//...do something...
}
```

Now I want to get a brain new ldap object, could I do it like this?

```
bp::object main_module_2 = bp::import("__main__");
bp::import("ldap");
bp::import("ldif");
bp::object main_namespace_2 = main_module_2.attr("__dict__");

bp::exec("import ldap,ldif\n"
         "l = ldap.initialize('ldaps://RIO-PC')\n",
         main_namespace);

//get the ldap object from the main_namespace
boost::python::object ldap_2 = boost::python::extract<boost::python::object>(main_namespace_2["l"]);
```

If this is unsafe, what should I do?If this is safe, do I have another options?

environment :
boost version : 1_55_0
compiler : vc2008
os : win7 64bits

Answer (score 0):

> Now I want to get a brain new ldap object, could I do it like this?

Yes you can. The [ldap](http://www.python-ldap.org/doc/html/ldap.html) module is a wrapper over the OpenLDAP C API, and as such if the documentation of the python module isn't clear enough in itself, you can always consult the original documentation [[1](http://www.openldap.org/software/man.cgi?query=ldap_init&sektion=3&apropos=0&manpath=OpenLDAP+2.1-Release),[2](http://linux.die.net/man/3/ldap_init)]. There you will find that the LDAP structure returned from the `open`/`init`/`initialize` method calls is a per-connection descriptor.

---

To further increase your confidence, you can verify that on your particular platform the object is not reused. You can do so by checking that the returned python object identifiers (`id(obj)`) are different:

```
#include <boost/python.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    namespace bp = boost::python;    
    Py_Initialize();

    bp::object main_module = bp::import("__main__");
    bp::import("ldap");
    bp::object main_namespace = main_module.attr("__dict__");
    bp::exec(
         "import ldap\n"
         "a = ldap.initialize('ldaps://tls.example.com')\n"
         "b = ldap.initialize('ldaps://tls.example.com')\n",
         main_namespace);

    boost::python::object a = boost::python::extract<
        boost::python::object>(main_namespace["a"]);
    boost::python::object b = boost::python::extract<
        boost::python::object>(main_namespace["b"]);
    std::cout << "id(a) = " << reinterpret_cast<long>(a.ptr()) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "id(b) = " << reinterpret_cast<long>(b.ptr()) << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: @user3518786 Does this help with your question?